# Second and third function in sparkR

Tags: r, dataframe, sparkr

In sparkR I have a DataFrame `data`. It contains `user`, `game`.

`user` contains the users and `game` contains the name of a game a user has played. There are only 14 games, namely 1,2,...,14.

So

```
head(data)
```

gives this output

```
user  game
3521     3
52      14
865      4
52       3
```

I want to find the first game a fixed user is playing. For example user 52 plays game 14 3 3 5 10 and here game 14 is the first game this user was playing.

In sparkR I do it this way

```
su <- groupBy(data, data$user)
sus <- agg(su, FirstPlayed= first(data$game))
# Making it local
local_sus <- collect(sus)
```

Here I get the correct result because I can use the `first` function in sparkR.

I want to find the 'second' and 'third' game a user has played but I can't do that because sparkR don't have a "second" function.

How should one then solve it - maybe I should use the `except`-function to delete the first element ?

Comment: How you identify that user 52 play 14 number game. I mean, does your data has timestamp field OR You just taking order of data insertion?

Comment: Its given in the data-set, so the dataset is ordered already.